# Gitignore content is being ignored

Tags: reactjs, git, firebase, github, gitignore

I created a simple community app using firebase as an exercise using the create-react-app command.

At this time, `firebase.js` is created and stored here for things related to firebase security, and `firebase.js` is imported from App.js where the main page is located.

The reason I made `firebase.js` separately is that I tried to ignore `firebase.js` with gitignore because I was trying to upload the project to GitHub, but it would be dangerous if important information was leaked.

I added `/src/firebase.js` to `.gitignore`, but firebase.js was still visible in the GitHub repository.

**TLDR**

I entered `/src/firebase.js` in gitignore, but `firebase.js` was still showing up.

Comment: `.gitignore` only affect files that are _not_ tracked. If the file is tracked, you need to remove it... at least from git, that is. I would be willing to bet that some 50% of questions related to `.gitignore` not working deal with this situation and there are plenty of answers on how to deal with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` only ignores specified untracked files; any untracked file listed in `.gitignore` will never be tracked. It does not retroactively remove already-tracked files from Git. (This is mentioned a few times in [the gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).)

The catchier version of that last paragraph: it's `.gitignore`, not `.gitforget`.

If you'd like Git to stop tracking a file, then use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: I've added /src/firebase.js to gitignore, but I'd like to ask you about /src/firebase.js still being seen on the github page.

Comment: It's still on the GitHub page because it's still in the repo. You need to run the remove command, then commit and push.